# WV Golf IV '98 - Right side blinkers not working on signal

Tags: electrical, vw, golf

I own a used VW Golf IV, 98, 1.4. I am facing a really strange issue the last few days. When I turn my hazzards on, every bulb works well and on time. When I signal left it works too. The problem is when I try to signal right. None of the right blinkers light up, my dashboard right blinker indicator stays off and the flashing sound is faster than normal.

Any ideas why ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

It sounds as though the turn signal switch has gone bad. The contacts inside the switch are probably just worn out. Not sure on your Golf, but I believe these are pretty easy to purchase and to replace.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This indeed seems like a faulty switch. I've done my online search and I can't say that the fix is expensive.

Comment: @KonstantinosKoletsas - Not only should it not be an expensive fix, it should be relatively easy to do as a DIY project.

Comment: Sounds like a challenge I'd love to take.